# Using App Engine Python application as proxy to PHP application

Tags: php, python, google-app-engine, http, proxy

During the past two years I have built an App Engine application in Python. Soon it will be possible to use PHP on App Engine. I would like to use off-the-shelf PHP applications such as Wordpress, Mediawiki and phpBB together with my Python application. To the user it should be transparent which of the two applications (Python or PHP) she is using for a particular page. I consider the Python application to be the main application where I will do most of the programming. This is because I have more experience with Python and also because I already have written a lot of reusable code for App Engine.

Currently my approach is to build a proxy in Python that maps HTTP requests like this:

---

`http://www.yellow.com/blog/*` to `http://phpapp.appspot.com/wordpress/client1/*`

`http://www.yellow.com/community/*` to `http://phpapp.appspot.com/phpbb/client1/*`

`yellow.com` is a domain mapped to my Python application.

---

`http://www.blue.com/wiki/*` to `http://phpapp.appspot.com/mediawiki/client2/*`

`http://www.blue.com/*` to `http://phpapp.appspot.com/wordpress/client2/*`

`blue.com` is a domain mapped to my Python application.

---

Besides the blog, community or wiki, there are a lot of URL's that don't require PHP. These URL's are handled by the Python application. For example: `http://www.yellow.com/admin/*`.

I'm still struggling with the proxy to get the passing of cookies between the two applications right, but I think it's possible to do this.

It would be awesome if I could get it to work this way. However, it seems to me this is not the most elegant way to handle this. I know I could use subdomains to serve the PHP applications, but I would rather just use URL patterns. Also, with the proxy approach, I can tweak the returned HTML by the PHP application before serving it to the user. Another advantage of this approach is the ability to cache the pages from the PHP applications in memcache.

I would like to hear what you think of my approach to use Google App Engine (custom) Python and (off-the-shelf) PHP applications together. Will I run into problems with the proxy (Javascript, cookies, ...)? Would it be better to build everything in Wordpress, for example, with custom plugins written in PHP (the plugins could fetch data from the Python application)? Other suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your use case is a good example of what [Appengine's Modules](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/modules/) are intended for. Take also a look at the [dispatch mechanism](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/modules/routing#dispatch_file).

Comment: Is it (or will it be) possible to have a module with the Python runtime environment and another module with the PHP runtime environment within the same application?